# iOS simulator not starting up

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I am trying to run the sample example for Xamarin.Forms. I have made the sample application. I have added the required packages in the project.But for some reason I am getting the the error

> *Failed to launch the simulator: Could not load the framework  'libswiftCore.dylib' (path:
>   /Applications/Xcode8beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib):
>   not found. error MT1008: Failed to launch the simulator: Could not
>   load the framework 'libswiftCore.dylib' (path:
>   /Applications/Xcode8beta.app/Contents/Frameworks/libswiftCore.dylib):
>   not found.*

I am using XCode 8 beta on my Mac
Xamarin studio 6.1.1

I have set the paths for the SDK correctly in the Xamarin preferences and it is saying that the SDK is available at the path that has been mentioned.
Whenever I try to run the application it compiles well but just before the simulator is expected to start it shows the above message.[image]

How should I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Upgrade to at least Xcode 8.0 (NON-Beta) and Xamarin Cycle 8, This supports the final Apple releases of iOS 10 and Xcode 8.  Or upgrade to Xcode 8.1 and most recent Xamarin Cycle 8 Service Release 0 (Xamarin.iOS 10.2.0.4) (see: https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-8-service-release-0-w-xcode8-1-support/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to update Xamarin Studio (and/or Visual Studio). [This](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-8-service-release-0-w-xcode8-1-support/) is the release that fixes it. [Here](https://releases.xamarin.com/technical-bulletin-xcode-8-1-gm/) is the post about the issue with the corresponding bugs that match your exactly.

Summary, Xcode 8.1 changed the location of the library so it caused Xamarin to error. Xamarin released a hotfix to the stable channel that resolves it.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I am able to start the iOS simulator . But the android part of the project is still throwing errors during compilation . I have just created simple project and upgraded my Android studio to reflect the latest changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try updating to a stable version of Xcode.

From the [Xamarin.iOS 10.0 release notes](https://developer.xamarin.com/releases/ios/xamarin.ios_10/xamarin.ios_10.0/#Requirements):

- The latest features and API requires Xcode 8.0 GM and the bundled iOS, tvOS and watchOS SDKs
- Apple Xcode 8.0 requires a Mac running OSX 10.11.5 (El Capitan) or newer

Builds supporting the final release of Xcode 8.1 have just been [released](https://releases.xamarin.com/stable-release-cycle-8-service-release-0-w-xcode8-1-support/), so that is also an option.